# How to properly format an argument that is a struct with nested structs, with web3.py?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, web3.py, struct

I have the following ABI:

```
{
    "inputs": [{
            "components": [{
                    "internalType": "enum LibNFTOrder.TradeDirection",
                    "name": "direction",
                    "type": "uint8"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "maker",
                    "type": "address"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "taker",
                    "type": "address"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "expiry",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "nonce",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "contract IERC20TokenV06",
                    "name": "erc20Token",
                    "type": "address"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "erc20TokenAmount",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }, {
                    "components": [{
                            "internalType": "address",
                            "name": "recipient",
                            "type": "address"
                        }, {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "amount",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        }, {
                            "internalType": "bytes",
                            "name": "feeData",
                            "type": "bytes"
                        }
                    ],
                    "internalType": "struct LibNFTOrder.Fee[]",
                    "name": "fees",
                    "type": "tuple[]"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "contract IERC1155Token",
                    "name": "erc1155Token",
                    "type": "address"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "erc1155TokenId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }, {
                    "components": [{
                            "internalType": "contract IPropertyValidator",
                            "name": "propertyValidator",
                            "type": "address"
                        }, {
                            "internalType": "bytes",
                            "name": "propertyData",
                            "type": "bytes"
                        }
                    ],
                    "internalType": "struct LibNFTOrder.Property[]",
                    "name": "erc1155TokenProperties",
                    "type": "tuple[]"
                }, {
                    "internalType": "uint128",
                    "name": "erc1155TokenAmount",
                    "type": "uint128"
                }
            ],
            "internalType": "struct LibNFTOrder.ERC1155Order",
            "name": "order",
            "type": "tuple"
        }
    ],
    "name": "getERC1155OrderHash",
    "outputs": [{
            "internalType": "bytes32",
            "name": "orderHash",
            "type": "bytes32"
        }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
```

---

And I want to make a call to that contract but I keep getting the error

> web3.exceptions.ValidationError:
> Could not identify the intended function with name `getERC1155OrderHash`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'dict'>,)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
> Found 1 function(s) with the name `getERC1155OrderHash`: ['getERC1155OrderHash(tuple)']
> Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

In the Web3.py docs it says that structs arguments can be passed as a dictionary and but that didn't work for me, and I can't find my mistake:

```
order = {'direction':0, 'maker': '0x6bea7d5f80ab338e11f1a98a69d81ec669f88a28','taker':'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000','expiry': 2524604400, 'nonce': '110201411100000000000000000000000000000051746150322622858142265866466119123410','erc20Token':'0xdc31ee1784292379fbb2964b3b9c4124d8f89c60', 'erc20TokenAmount': 5000000000000000000, 'fees': [['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 0, b'0']], 'erc1155Token':'0xfc37b8f25b57bff5c1b6df2d76485079bdc133cf', 'erc1155TokenId':1665619200,'erc1155TokenProperties':[['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', b'0']], 'erc1155TokenAmount':5000000000000000000}
```

This is for the 0x protocol on the Goerli network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually means that one or more arguments of your `getERC1155OrderHash` function are of incorrect type. Please check to make sure your `getERC1155OrderHash` function has the correct argument types. In addition, check to make sure there are no double quotes nor spaces at the beginning or end of your addresses.